# Duration tracking in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-moment, angular-timer

Im trying to handle durationc calculation in my `AngularJS` app.
If User logged In then it should show timer counting time in `Hr` and `Mins`.
for example. User logged in since 15 minutes passed then UI should show

LoggedIn time: `0hr 15m`.

I tried to user `angular-timer and angular-moment`  and it works but when user SignOut it still continue showing timer running.

below is HTML code used in `angular-timer`

```
<i class="ti-alarm-clock"></i><timer start-time="visit.SignInTime" end-time="1476990000000">{{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds</timer><br />
```

`end-time` not working with `start-time` .

Comment: Do you call the `stop` method?

Comment: @taguenziy `stop` method stops all timers on page . thats not I want

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can `stop` a single one, just need the correct implementation. [angular-timer](https://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/)